# Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:

Tags: php, wordpress

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Medicine\wp-content\plugins\medilazar-core\inc\class-import.php on line 187

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\xampp\htdocs\Medicine\wp-content\plugins\medilazar-core\inc\class-import.php on line 187

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://localhost/Medicine/wp-content/plugins/medilazar-core/dummy-data/config.json): failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Medicine\wp-content\plugins\medilazar-core\inc\class-import.php on line 187

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HpPo.png)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your question so that you can get help much faster.

Answer (score -4):

Using cURL with SSL verification disabled should resolve the problem;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```